# Ranking a data frame ascending in one column and the descending in another

Tags: python, pandas

I've found out how to rank a data frame with multiple columns but only if they're all descending or ascending order however I'm looking to rank a data frame in ascending order and then if there's a tie using a second column ordered by descending order.

This is what I'm looking for:

| # of hits | % chance | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2 |
| 2 | 100 | 3 |
| 1 | 95 | 1 |
| 3 | 75 | 5 |
| 2 | 60 | 4 |

This is what I currently have:

df['Rank'] = df["# of hits"].rank(ascending=True,method="dense").astype(int)

This is what I have at the moment and then I have a column which is basically '% chance' so therefore 100% is the 'best' in the rank. I can't find anything that ranks in "two directions" so I'm currently using an IF statement to check if there are two Rank == 1 and then a lot more IF statements to resolve the tie but I figured there must be a better way to rank these data frames.

Answer (score 1):

```
col1=df1.sort_values(df1.columns.tolist(),ascending=[True,False]).assign(col1=range(1,df1.pipe(len)+1)).col1
df1.assign(rank=col1)
```

Output:

```
  ofhits  chance  rank
0       1      50     2
1       2     100     3
2       1      95     1
3       3      75     5
4       2      60     4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with your custom order, then [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
df['Rank'] = np.argsort(df.reset_index(drop=True) # optional
                          .sort_values(by=['# of hits', '% chance'],
                                       ascending=[True, False])
                          .index)+1
```

*NB.  the [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) is optional, you only need it if the index is not already sorted.*

Output:

```
   # of hits  % chance  Rank
0          1        50     2
1          2       100     3
2          1        95     1
3          3        75     5
4          2        60     4
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'# of hits': [1, 2, 1, 3, 2],
                   '% chance': [50, 100, 95, 75, 60]})
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input as `DataFrame` constructor?

Comment: The original response has worked after I added the reset_index. Thank you!

Comment: OK, then your original index was not sorted ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `rank(method='first)`

```
df['Rank'] = df.sort_values('% chance',ascending=False)['# of hits'].rank(method = 'first').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   # of hits  % chance  Rank
0          1        50     2
1          2       100     3
2          1        95     1
3          3        75     5
4          2        60     4
```